# Markdown Images, Links, and Accessibility

Tags: html, markdown, accessibility, github-flavored-markdown

## Images

[image: Flag Icon] Icons

Both of the markdown code blocks below generate the image and text above on GitHub.

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Flag_font_awesome.svg/24px-Flag_font_awesome.svg.png" alt="Flag Icon" role="img" aria-label="Flag Icon" /> Icons
```

```
![Flag Icon](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Flag_font_awesome.svg/24px-Flag_font_awesome.svg.png) Icons
```

## Links

[Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) icons

Both of the markdown code blocks below generate the link and text above on GitHub.

```
<a href="https://fontawesome.com/" role="link" aria-label="Visit the Font Awesome website">Font Awesome</a> icons
```

```
[Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) icons
```

I am trying to make markdown as accessible as possible. Which of the formats in both the images and links would provide the best accessibility experience on GitHub? Or are the experiences the same?

Further, is there anything else I should be doing to enhance the accessibility experience with markdown?

Comment: This likely depends at least in part on the Markdown processor you are using. They don't necessarily all generate the same HTML. How are you rendering these?

Comment: Should have specified, this is for rendering in GitHub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since different Markdown processors may render Markdown differently, the best thing to do is to try this out and compare the rendered results.

Based on a simple Gist, it looks like the results are identical on GitHub. In that case, from an accessibility perspective there is no difference.